# How do I move the value of a variant<Ts...> into a variant<T,Ts...>?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variant

Is there an easy way to move the data contained in some `std::variant<Ts...>` into an `std::variant<T,Ts...>`?

I suppose there is the option to switch over all types in `Ts...` with an extra class template, but I wonder if there is a more elegant in-place way to do this.

Example:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::variant<T,Ts...> use(std::optional<T>&& opt, std::variant<Ts...>&& var) {
  if (opt.has_value()) return *opt;
  else return magic<T,T...>(var);
}
```

Comment: I don't happen to use C++17, but I highly doubt that it's possible. You see, `operation =` is highly dependant on the type of variable. So you cannot escape from iterating over all the types (hypothetically, if types were trivially copyable then memcopying could make it shorter, but it isn't a generic solution). Surely, you can make it look pretty and generic with the visitor pattern but nothing beyond that.

Comment: @ALX23z Yeah, I'd like to direct your attention to the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can visit and then construct the new variant type:

```cpp
return std::visit([](auto&& arg) -> std::variant<T, Ts...> {
    return std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg);
}, std::move(var));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class Dest, class Var>
Dest variant_static_cast( Var&& var ){
  return std::visit( [](auto&& elem)->Dest {
    return static_cast<Dest>( decltype(elem)(elem) );
  }, std::forward<Var>(var) );
}
```

then

```
return variant_static_cast<std::variant<T,T...>>(std::move(var));
```

what this does is cast each possible type in the source variant to the destination type.